# play wav file in Raspberry Pi with Windows 10 IOT Core

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot

Could someone please give me some starting kick on how to play a simple wav file on Raspberry Pi under Windows 10? What I want is load a few files into memory and on specific events, start playing them, if possible, play the sounds at the same time as well.
I tried [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229685%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), but it failed with the DLLImport row (CoreDll.dll not found).
So, any clever link or sample is very welcome.
Thank you,
vm

I created a simple test project, it runs, exits without error, but I only hear silence. Am I doing something wrong? I expected that the code below plays a short drum sample 50 times.

```
namespace BackTC
{
    public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            btnPlayWavSound_Tapped();
        }


        private async void btnPlayWavSound_Tapped()
        {

            StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/CLudwigKick-Dyn01.WAV"));
            MediaPlayer player = BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current;
            player.SetFileSource(file);


            for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
            {
                player.Volume = 100;
                player.Play();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Try setting player.AutoPlay = false right before you do SetFileSource and that should then work. Also, Volume maxes out at 1.  For example, if you wanted to set it to 75%, you'd have to set it to 0.75.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've got the following code that will work in a Background Application project and it reads the WAV file from the Assets folder.  Don't forget to set the WAV file to copy to output directory.

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/filename.wav"));
MediaPlayer player = BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current;
player.AutoPlay = false;
player.SetFileSource(file);
player.Play();
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with a sample application I created based on your input.

Comment: Are you on the most recent version 10586? I ran into the same problem and had to set AutoPlay to false and then it worked.

Comment: I'd love to see the full IOT project where this snippet is from. Could you post it?